# Can't retrieve data from android sqlite database after asynchronous insertion

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

In the start activity i insert data into the database in AsyncTask and when it completes I start new Activity and select that data to show it in list view, but selected cursor is empty.
Here is a code of insertion and starting new Activity:

```
 dbOperations= DatabaseManager.getInstance(AuthorizationMainActivity.this);
            dbOperations.open();
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> parametersInbox = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            parametersInbox.put("_id", result.get("msg_id"));
            parametersInbox.put("limit", Integer.valueOf(1000).toString());
            parametersInbox.put("type", Integer.valueOf(1).toString());
            requestInbox(serverParametersInbox);//This method send request to the server and insert response into the database.
                           try {
                databaseTask.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent nextView = new Intent(context_, InboxActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextView);
```

And this is `InboxActivity` `onCreate()`:

```
DatabaseManager db = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
 db.open();
  String selectionQuery = "select * from messages;";
 database.rawQuery(selectionQuery, null).getCount(); //Here is 0!
```

So data inserts well (I can see it in the viewer). But in the next activity I can't retrieve it.Why? Before starting new Activity I call `get()` to wait while `AsyncTask` completes.

P.S Insertion space between select and * makes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DatabaseManager db = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
 db.open();
  String selectionQuery = "select * from messages;";
 database.rawQuery(selectionQuery, null).getCount(); //Here is 0!
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29) for the method `rawQuery` I quote:

> ...The SQL string must not be ; terminated

So, I suggest you remove the semicolon from your sql string.